# GoLand 2022.2.4: delve panic - version of Delve is too old for Go version 1.19.0

Tags: goland

Just upgraded to: GoLand 2022.2.4

And I did saw some Java stuff messagebox asking something. Now when ever I debug I get:

```
GOROOT=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.19/libexec #gosetup
GOPATH=/Users/<user>/go #gosetup
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.19/libexec/bin/go build -o /private/var/folders/ws/r3lmtqdj03d3jn5l3v3t_s3w0000gn/T/GoLand/___go_build_ngraph_server_worker -gcflags all=-N -l ngraph/server/worker #gosetup
/Applications/GoLand.app/Contents/plugins/go/lib/dlv/macarm/dlv --listen=127.0.0.1:61230 --headless=true --api-version=2 --check-go-version=false --only-same-user=false exec /private/var/folders/ws/r3lmtqdj03d3jn5l3v3t_s3w0000gn/T/GoLand/___go_build_ngraph_server_worker --
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:61230
debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:LLDB  PROJECT:lldb-1400.0.30.3
 for arm64.
Got a connection, launched process /private/var/folders/ws/r3lmtqdj03d3jn5l3v3t_s3w0000gn/T/GoLand/___go_build_ngraph_server_worker (pid = 84469).
WARNING: undefined behavior - version of Delve is too old for Go version 1.19.0 (maximum supported version 1.17)
<nil>
<nil>
Exiting.

Debugger finished with the exit code 0
```

Comment: Related https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/3280

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Delve was not updated during the IDE update.

You can download GoLand from https://www.jetbrains.com/go/download/#section=mac and replace the current installation to update Delve.

Answer (score 9):

I solved the issue in Goland using following instructions:

1. Install `dlv` binary with `go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest`
2. Set the `dlv.path=<path_to_dlv_executable>` under ***Help > Edit Custom Properties***
3. Restart GoLand

[Reference](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-14287)